# Java2D: Is it always safe to cast Graphics into Graphics2D

Tags: java, java-2d

Assuming we always use a Sun JVM (say, 1.5+), is it always safe to cast a Graphics reference to Graphics2D?

I haven't seen it cause any problems yet and, to my understanding, the Graphics class is legacy code but the Java designers didn't want to change the interfaces for Swing and AWT classes in order to preserver backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the discussion [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1350311?db=5), it **is always safe to cast from `Graphics` to `Graphics2D`**. However I am not able to quickly find the official Sun statement on this.

> The reason it is valid to cast from
>   Graphics to Graphics2D, is because Sun
>   have said that all Graphics objects
>   returned by the API in Java 1.2 or
>   above will be a subclass of
>   Graphics2D.

Another hint [here](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/staff/caron/java/JavaOne2003.html) with the same conclusion.

> Graphics Object can always be cast
>   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

Comment: Thanks for the references.  I'm going to accept this one even though it doesn't directly cite a Sun source because I think it's close enough.

Comment: As I remember all the Sun docs always show the cast for the Graphics2D stuff, so I assume it's safe. If you really want to be pedantic, you could use a try/catch block, but my guess is that if you have the Graphics2D classes (JVM/libs new enough), you're safe.

Comment: The first link is dead

Answer (score 11):

In the book [Filthy Rich Client](http://filthyrichclients.org) by Chet Haase and Romain Guy they are saying that Swing almost always uses a `Graphics2D` object. Exceptions from this are printing and Swing's `DebugGraphics` object. So as long as none of these situations apply to your code it is safe to cast to `Graphics2D`.
Both of the authors worked at Sun, so I would assume that they know what they are talking about.

Answer (score 7):

The [2D Graphics Trail](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/overview/rendering.html) says:

> To employ Java 2D API features in the application, cast the Graphics object passed into a component’s rendering method to a Graphics2D object. For example:

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    ...
}
```

This is the most "official" source I could find.  Coming straight from Sun's Java Tutorials, I'd say that this is the officially sanctioned way of doing it.  I wouldn't have exactly minded if the JavaDocs spelled this out, though...