# conversion to Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing

With swing is it granted that conversion

```
paint (Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    ......
}
```

will always work? Or there could be different graphics implementations, not only Graphics2D?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179415/java2d-is-it-always-safe-to-cast-graphics-into-graphics2d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is, yes it should work, unless you're using some other JVM.  I can't remember since when exactly, but Swings paint engine will always use a Graphics2D instance to perform its component painting