# Java - Swing - Graphics 2D

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, paintcomponent

```
public class Points extends JPanel {

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);

  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

  g2d.drawLine(60, 20, 80, 90);
 }
}
```

I'm not really sure what's the `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;` supposed to do.

It's just a plain JPanel that's later added onto a JFrame.

It would be really helpfull if anyone could give me some advice as I'm stuck at this line  of the code for a long time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
```

just casts the `Graphics` object to a `Graphics2D`. It's used to access the methods provided by `Graphics2D`. In this case it is unnecessary as `Graphics` also has a `drawLine` method so if you don't have a requirement for the more advanced methods such as `rotate` and `translate`, you can use

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.drawLine(60, 20, 80, 90);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that you can do this with objects at all.
 
Im pretty new to programming and when I learned some of the basics I just jumped into coding, so theres a lot of things that I've skipped in the tutorial

Comment: And one last thing, you can cast an object only to a subclass, right ?

Comment: Not only to a subclass. In this case `Graphics2D` is a subclass of `Graphics` so you cast or more correctly downcast the reference `g`. But more generally if any Object implements an interface then you can cast to that interface also. You can cast provided the Object **is-a** type of the other object.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of compatibility with older Java code.

`Graphics2D`, as explained in documentation, is a class that inherits from `Graphics` and provides some additional graphic features: in short `Graphics2D` is a more powerful `Graphics`.

Now, the method `paintComponent(Graphics g)` exists from before `Graphics2D` so even if with current Java the Graphics which is under the hood of a JPanel is a `Graphics2D`, the signature hasn't been changed to break existing code.

At runtime the `g` passed is a `Graphics2D` but you need to cast it so that you will be allowed to call more advanced operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

It casts the graphics context into a `Graphics2D` object. This is useful because `Graphics2D` allows for rotations, transformations, antialiasing, etc not possible with a normal `Graphics` object. All of the methods available in `Graphics` are still available to you when you use `Graphics2D`.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting `g` as a `Graphics2D` so you can get at the advanced functionality in the `Graphics2D` class.

Answer (score 0):

That just casts your `Graphics` object into a `Graphics2D` object.  `Graphics2D` has a lot of features that `Graphics` doesn't provide that are very useful for painting 2D graphics.  Check out the documentation for Graphics2D here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html

Also, according to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179415/java2d-is-it-always-safe-to-cast-graphics-into-graphics2d), that cast should always be safe to do.