# Getting the Graphics2D?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, applet, graphics2d

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; //

    double r = 100; //the radius of the circle

    //draw the circle

    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 2 * r, 2 * r);
    g2.draw(circle);
```

This is part of a class within my program, my question lies in the

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
```

Why must you include the "g" after the  (Graphics2D), and what exactly does the "Graphics2D" Within the parenthesis mean, i am learning out of a book and neither of these were ever fully explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting `Graphics2D` to the `Graphics` context `g`. Read more about casting here in [**Inheritance**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) in the **Casting** section.

What this ultimately does is allot you use the available methods of `Graphics2D` with the `Graphics` context of the passed to the `paintComponent` method. Whitout the casting, you'd only be limited to the methods of the `Graphics` class

`Graphics2D` is a subclass of `Graphics` so by using `Graphics2D` you gain all the methods of `Graphics` while taking advantage of the methods in the `Graphics2D` class.

---

**Side Notes**

- You shouldn't be override `paint`. Also if you are, you shouldn't be painting on top level containers like `JApplet`.
- Instead paint on a `JPanel` or `JComponent` and override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` and call `super.paintComponent`. Then just add the `JPanel` to the parent container.

  ```
  public DrawPanel extends JPanel {
      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
      }
  }
  ```

See more at [**Custom Painting**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [**Graphics2D**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must include the `g`.

When you enter your paint method you have an object `g` of type `Graphics`.

Then you are typecasting your `Graphics` object, `g` to a type of `Graphics2D` which is a type that extends `Graphics`.

You have to include the `g` so you have something to typecast. If you don't include object there you will get a compilation error because the statement isn't complete.

The reason you are typecasting `g` to a `Graphics2D` object is because you are telling the compiler, "This Graphics object is actually a Graphics2D object." that way you can perform functions that the `Graphics2D` Object has that the the `Graphics` object does not.

This **[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java)** explains casting variables in Java very well if you have more questions about that. And this **[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179415/java2d-is-it-always-safe-to-cast-graphics-into-graphics2d)** explains why it is safe to cast from `Graphics` to `Graphics2D`