# Why does this casting from a super to a sub-interface work?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm looking at this example from a [Spring Boot guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/):

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}
```

And am confused by this line:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
```

I understand the cast from `ServletResponse` to `HttpServletResponse` is necessary because the latter interface has `#setHeader()`. But why does this cast work? Does it work because the underlying object passed to the method is a `HttpServletResponse`?

But runtime aside, why does the compiler allow this? I'm new to Java and would have expected this cast to fail, since it's from a less to more specific type. For example, using [Element](http://www.tinkerpop.com/javadocs/3.0.0.M6/core/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Element.html) and [Vertex](http://www.tinkerpop.com/javadocs/3.0.0.M6/core/com/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Vertex.html), I've had this fail:

```
Vertex v = (Vertex) e; // `e` is an `Element`
```

Comment: You are allowed to cast to any subtype, however the JVM will yell at you at runtime if the type is incorrect, of course

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380813/downcasting-in-java

Comment: I've had compilation errors when trying to convert from a supertype to a subtype.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis, will read that. Didn't know the exact terminology ("downcasting", etc).

Comment: @dimadima Which makes sense, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton what, specifically? I'd would have thought the compiler didn't allow this. Then again, I haven't read S. Delimanolis' link yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6) pretty much explains it perfectly.

> 5.1.6 Narrowing Reference Conversion
>
> Such conversions require a test at run time to find out whether the actual reference value is a legitimate value of the new type. If not, then a ClassCastException is thrown.

i.e. When you do such a conversion you *explicitly cast* the type S to the type T. By doing so you are telling the compiler "I am sure this is ok".

If you think it *might* fail, then you should `try...catch` for a `ClassCastException` and stop your program terminating unexpectedly.

Comment: I guess this would be a commonly-requested/desired feature of the spec, but it seems to be poor form if you're looking for type safety?

Comment: @dimadima Not all type safety information can be inferred at compile time. Casting is an *explicit request by the developer* to do something at runtime. The implementation of the super type might not even be in your code, like in the servlet spec.

Comment: There are also sometimes when an API can not change the types in the parameters to preserve backwards compatability.  So the Java authors had to make new subtypes  with additional methods that are **guaranteed** to always work as a downcast. for example in Java Swing the `Graphics` objects can always be downcast to `Graphics2D` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179415/java2d-is-it-always-safe-to-cast-graphics-into-graphics2d

Comment: @dkatzel thanks for this. This is a great example to my question of "why". The answer here says that "The JLS pretty much explain it perfectly." I don't know why describing the behavior means it's explained perfectly. In fact, its only your example that really explains WHY.

Comment: @dimadima "*why does this cast work?*": the JLS specifies that it is allowed to (as per the detail in my answer). "*why does the compiler allow this?*": because it obeys/enforces the JLS. Perhaps your third "*why*" is "*why does the JLS allow NRCs to cause a CCE*": the short answer is that it was the way it was designed; without this many features in the language would require redesign.